# Connect DynamoDB to an Android Application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having trouble finding resources or tutorials about how to interact with data in a DynamoDB table through an Android Application. I have looked at the Amplify for Mobile Apps tutorial (https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/android#add-amplify-to-your-application) but it really doesn't show me where and how I can work with DynamoDB. There is an old AWS SDK with DynamoDB classes to work with but there's no proper tutorials for this. Has anyone tried to do this before and where can I find info for it?